# "'Credentials' object has no attribute 'access_token'" when using google-auth with gspread

Tags: python, google-api, google-authentication, oauth2client

I'd like to use [`gspread`](http://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) module to edit Google sheets from Python. The [setup instructions](http://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/oauth2.html) contain the following example:

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds',
         'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']

credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('gspread-april-2cd … ba4.json', scope)

gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)
```

However, according to https://pypi.org/project/oauth2client/ the `oauth2client` library is deprecated. So I've tried to adapt this as follows, using [`google-auth`](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/):

```
import gspread
from google.oauth2 import service_account

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    'my_client_secrets.json')

scoped_credentials = credentials.with_scopes(
    ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets'])

gc = gspread.authorize(scoped_credentials)
```

Unfortunately, I'm running into the following error:

```
(lucy-web-CVxkrCFK) bash-3.2$ python nps.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "nps.py", line 54, in <module>
    gc = gspread.authorize(scoped_credentials)
  File "/Users/kurtpeek/.local/share/virtualenvs/lucy-web-CVxkrCFK/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gspread/__init__.py", line 38, in authorize
    client.login()
  File "/Users/kurtpeek/.local/share/virtualenvs/lucy-web-CVxkrCFK/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gspread/client.py", line 46, in login
    if not self.auth.access_token or \
AttributeError: 'Credentials' object has no attribute 'access_token'
```

If I drop into the debugger, I indeed see that `credentials` has a `token` attribute, but not an `access_token` one:

```
> /Users/kurtpeek/Documents/Dev/lucy2/lucy-web/scripts/nps.py(54)<module>()
     53 import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
---> 54 gc = gspread.authorize(scoped_credentials)
     55 

ipdb> type(credentials)
<class 'google.oauth2.service_account.Credentials'>
ipdb> type(scoped_credentials)
<class 'google.oauth2.service_account.Credentials'>
ipdb> dir(credentials)
['__abstractmethods__', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_abc_impl', '_additional_claims', '_from_signer_and_info', '_make_authorization_grant_assertion', '_project_id', '_scopes', '_service_account_email', '_signer', '_subject', '_token_uri', 'apply', 'before_request', 'expired', 'expiry', 'from_service_account_file', 'from_service_account_info', 'has_scopes', 'project_id', 'refresh', 'requires_scopes', 'scopes', 'service_account_email', 'sign_bytes', 'signer', 'signer_email', 'token', 'valid', 'with_claims', 'with_scopes', 'with_subject']
```

Are the `Credentials` generated by `google-auth` not the same objects as the ones generated by `oauth2client`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per the `gspread` documentation, the [gspread.authorize](http://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#gspread.authorize) method only supports credential objects that are created by the [oauth2client library](https://github.com/google/oauth2client). To work with the new [google-auth](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) one, gspread should add support for it.

A possible workaroud, if you don't want to use the oauthclient2 that is deprecated, is to use [authlib](https://authlib.org/) leveraging the session parameter of the [gspread.Client](http://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#gspread.Client) class. There is a nice tutorial on how to do this [here](https://blog.authlib.org/2018/authlib-for-gspread).

#### Update April 27 2020

Starting from [version 3.4.0](https://github.com/burnash/gspread/releases/tag/v3.4.0) gspread is now supporting [google-auth](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). You can find all the details in the [dedicated documentation](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/oauth2.html#for-bots-using-service-account). Here is an official statement from the author:

> Older versions of gspread have used [oauth2client](https://github.com/google/oauth2client). Google has [deprecated](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/oauth2client-deprecation.htmla) it in favor of google-auth. If you’re still using oauth2client credentials, the library will convert these to google-auth for you, but you can change your code to use the new credentials to make sure nothing breaks in the future.

Comment: Since this was posted, GSpread has added access for the new google-auth credentials: https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/oauth2.html

Comment: @Alec is correct. gspread has been using google-auth since version 3.4.0.

Comment: @Burnash and Alec (Stackoverflow only allow me to have one tag) Thanks for pointing out the news. I've updated my answer accordingly, let me know if it looks good to you.

Answer (score 5):

A year and a half later in quite the same situation, I found this to work for me:

```
import gspread
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from google.auth.transport.requests import AuthorizedSession

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    'your_key_file.json')

scoped_credentials = credentials.with_scopes(
        ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds',
         'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
        )

gc = gspread.Client(auth=scoped_credentials)
gc.session = AuthorizedSession(scoped_credentials)
sheet = gc.open_by_key('key_in_sharelink')
print(sheet.title)
```

Solution was adapted from [this post](https://github.com/burnash/gspread/issues/472#issuecomment-317631725) in gspread github and the `google-auth` [user guide](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html).

Comment: It also worked for me replacing oauth2client usage with google.oauth2. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As a band-aide fix, you can create a new class that inherits the credentials and adds a new `access_token` property that mirrors the token in the credentials. Then pass that into `gspread.authorize` and it should work.

```
# create the new class to fix credentials
class fixed_creds(service_account.Credentials):
    def __init__(self, creds):
        self.access_token = creds.token

# create new credential object with the access_token
gcreds = fixed_creds(credentials)

# pass new credentials into gspread
sheets = gspread.authorize(gcreds)

# create a new sheet to test it
new_sheet = sheets.create('TestSheet')

# give yourself permission to see the new sheet
sheets.insert_permission(
    new_sheet.id,
    'youremail@yourdomain.com',
    perm_type='user',
    role='writer'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The band aid fix from Tom didnt work for me because `token` was initially `None` in Google OAuth2 library. Here's my band aid fix:

```py
import gspread
import google.auth.transport.requests
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

class OAuth2ServiceAccountFromGoogleOAuth2(ServiceAccountCredentials):  # Hack based upon https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51618127/credentials-object-has-no-attribute-access-token-when-using-google-auth-wi
    def __init__(self, google_oauth2_credentials):
        self.google_oauth2_credentials = google_oauth2_credentials
        self.access_token = google_oauth2_credentials.token

    def refresh(self, http):
        if self.access_token is None:
            request = google.auth.transport.requests.Request()
            self.google_oauth2_credentials.refresh(request)
            self.access_token = self.google_oauth2_credentials.token
        #end if

        print(f'access token in {self.access_token}')
    #end def
#end class

with open("credentials.json") as gs_key_file:
    google_credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(json.loads(gs_key_file.read()), scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets'])
gclient = gspread.authorize(OAuth2ServiceAccountFromGoogleOAuth2(google_credentials))
```